# json null values returned [snowflake]

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, webui

I imported my own JSON into Snowflake (single column variant). When I ran a select my JSON column is null.

I thought it might be an issue in my dataset but I also used the sample data in the link
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html

This is also returning null when I run
`SELECT src:dealership FROM car_sales;`

Currently using Firefox webui, but also tried the Snowcli with same NULL result.
I'm running snow standard.

tia

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your JSON (anonymized vales if necessary) and SQL sample of how you've tried reading the JSON?

Comment: Make sure in this case that you field name is `src` and your attribute name is `dealership` and that the attribute is in fact all lowercase (attributes are case-sensitive).  Otherwise, a sample of your JSON would be very helpful.

Comment: do a select * and make sure your hierarchy is as expected (as in you didn't put an extra level of {}-s in there or sth)